# How to produce a generic Makefile for various projects with the same folder structure?

Tags: c, makefile

I have to following folder structure in various projects :

```
myproject/
   obj/
   src/
     file1.c
     file2.c
     file3.c
   inc/
     myproject.h
   Makefile
```

I have the following Makefile :

```
NAME        :=  myproject

CC          :=  gcc
RM          :=  rm

CFLAGS      :=  -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS     :=  -Wall
RMFLAGS     :=  -f

SRCDIR      :=  src
OBJDIR      :=  obj
INCDIR      :=  inc

HEADERS     :=  $(INCDIR)/myproject.h

LINK.o      :=  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
COMPILE.c   :=  $(CC) -I$(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) -c

SRCS        :=  file1.c file2.c file3.c

SOURCES     :=  $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCS))
OBJECTS     :=  $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS) Makefile
    $(LINK.o) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Here is what I am looking to achieve :

- I would like to put all .o files under obj/.
- The final executable should be at the root of the myproject/ folder.
- If a .c file changes, only this file should be recompiled.
- If the Makefile or the .h changes, I would like to recompile everything.

However, I when I run this Makefile I get `make: *** No rule to make target` obj/file1.o', needed by `myproject'.  Stop.`.

Could anyone help me fix this Makefile and give me advice on how to improve it?

EDIT
Here is a new version of the Makefile based on the comments.

```
NAME        :=  myproject

CC          :=  gcc
RM          :=  rm

CFLAGS      :=  -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS     :=  -Wall
RMFLAGS     :=  -f

SRCDIR      :=  src
OBJDIR      :=  obj
INCDIR      :=  inc

HEADERS     :=  $(INCDIR)/myproject.h

LINK.o      :=  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
COMPILE.c   :=  $(CC) -I$(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) -c
REMOVE      :=  $(RM) $(RMFLAGS)

SRCS        :=  file1.c file2.c file3.c

SOURCES     :=  $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCS))
OBJECTS     :=  $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK.o) -o $(NAME) $^

clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJECTS)

fclean: clean
    $(REMOVE) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

This version works, but I am still unsure how to trigger recompilation of the Makefile or the .h changes.

Comment: `%` is only the wildcard for pattern substitution. For normal uses, use `*`. `$(OBJDIR)/*.o: $(SRCDIR)/*.c` See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html

Comment: Something in your question does not add up.   If you run `make clean`, it should output `rm obj/file1.o  obj/file2.o  obj/file3.o`...   (note the lack of `-f` in there).   So, you either misquoted the output, are not running `make clean`, or there is more to the makefile than you're showing.    One quick hint -- use lines like `$(info OBJECTS:$(OBJECTS))` to inspect your variables -- you might get some insight as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that `rc: fclean all` does not guarentee that `fclean` will finish before `all` starts building...   (namely if you build with `-j`).   Even if you don't build with `-j`, it's not good practice to make that assumption.

Comment: A third thing -- if you want to rebuild all of your objects if any of the headers is modified, you need to make your objects dependent on the headers.   In this case, adding the line `$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS)` should do it.

Comment: As HardcoreHenry says, there's no way that the makefile you show will print `rm -f file1.c file2.c file3.c` when you run `make clean`.  Either the makefile you are using has some material difference from the one you show above, or the output you get is different than what you showed us.

Comment: @MadScientist You are right, rm -f does show the correct output I don't know what I did wrong. I will update the OP.

Comment: You need to use `%` not `*` in your pattern rule.  It should be `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c` not `$(OBJDIR)/*.o: $(SRCDIR)/*.c`.  I'm not sure what the first comment by Schwern is referring to but it's definitely not right to use `*` in a pattern rule.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks I have updated to OP accordingly.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I mention adding the line `$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS)` but where should I add that line ?

Comment: You can added it anywhere (after you've defined those variables).  But you should add it after the `all` rule if you want `all` to be the default rule that's run when you type `make` with no arguments.  Also if you want to recompile if the makefile changes you have to add that as well: `$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS) Makefile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MadScientist and @HardcoreHenry I have managed to fix the Makefile. Here is the final version :

```
# Edit the $(NAME) and $(SRCS) variables as necessary.
NAME        :=  myprogram
SRCS        :=  file1.c file2.c file3.c

CC          :=  gcc
RM          :=  rm

CFLAGS      :=  -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS     :=  -Wall
RMFLAGS     :=  -f

SRCDIR      :=  src
OBJDIR      :=  obj
INCDIR      :=  inc

# Edit the $(HEADERS) variable as necessary.
HEADERS     :=  $(INCDIR)/myprogram.h

LINK.o      :=  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
COMPILE.c   :=  $(CC) -I$(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) -c
REMOVE      :=  $(RM) $(RMFLAGS)

SOURCES     :=  $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCS))
OBJECTS     :=  $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

all: $(NAME)

$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS) Makefile

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK.o) -o $(NAME) $^

clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJECTS)

fclean: clean
    $(REMOVE) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```